# Change jar file icon for linux distributions

Tags: linux, jar, executable

I have an application .jar and I want to change the icon (instead of the default java icon).

For Windows distributions, I made that converting the jar file to an exe (I used exe4j). And it works.
But now I want to do something similar for linux distributions...

How can I do that? Which extension should I use? (I'm using windows 7)

P.S: Is not the frame icon that I want to change, because that I already changed by code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux file managers never look at the file to see what icon to use. If you want to have a specific image for your application then provide it as a separate file and create a [.desktop file](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) to connect your image to your executable.

[image: Contents of /usr/share/applications]